# Is there a way to read .env file, then conditionally require packages within composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php

My usecase:

I want to install `auth0/login` package, only if `.env` says `AUTH_PROVIDER=auth0` otherwise we do not need to install `auth0\login`.

Is this possible? if it is possible, what is the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to "conditionally" install packages is the `require-dev` key.

But it does not seem `auth0/login` is a dev package for you, so this wouldn't work.

Whatever is listed as a requirement in `composer.json` is installed, and having it any other way would be confusing for users of the project.

If it could be possible what you propose, a change in `.env` would require reinstalling the project... which is not what anyone would expect: `.env` holds **run-time** configuration, and `composer.json` holds **build-time** configuration.

Sorry, but what you want to do is not possible, and it's a bad idea.

If the package is used in some run-time configurations, it's a hard-requirement and should be installed. If under some configurations or scenarios is not used, it's perfectly fine.